# the forEach of Array is async compared to normal for loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise

I just start to explore `async/await` in es6, I find something really surprise me.Basically, `forEach` behave asynchronously while `for` loop behave synchronously  here is example

```
function getData(d) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            resolve(d.x+" %%%% ")
        },1000)
    })
}
const data=[{x:"aaa"},{x:"bbb"}]


//async for loop
const makeRequest1 = async () => {
    for (let i in data){
        let value=data[i]
        console.log(value)
        value.p=await getData(value)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(value)+ ' after')
    }
    // console.log(rr)
    console.log(data)
    console.log("Is it block ??")
    return "done"
}
// { x: 'aaa' }
// {"x":"aaa","p":"aaa %%%% "} after
// { x: 'bbb' }
// {"x":"bbb","p":"bbb %%%% "} after
// [ { x: 'aaa', p: 'aaa %%%% ' }, { x: 'bbb', p: 'bbb %%%% ' } ]
// Is it block ??
//     done



//async for loop
const makeRequest2 = async () => {
    data.forEach(async (value)=>{
        console.log(value)
        value.p=await getData(value)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(value)+ ' after')
    })
    console.log(data)
    console.log("Is it block ??")
    return "done"
}
// { x: 'aaa' }
// { x: 'bbb' }
// [ { x: 'aaa' }, { x: 'bbb' } ]
// Is it block ??
// done
// {"x":"aaa","p":"aaa %%%% "} after
// {"x":"bbb","p":"bbb %%%% "} after


makeRequest2().then((r)=>{
    console.log(r)
})
```

I know both `for` and `forEach` version should run synchronously, How come `forEach` become async in this case?

Comment: Maybe because of `async` in front of the callback...

Comment: @Weedoze very possible, Is there any detailed explanation

Comment: You are saying that you are exploring `async` and `await` then go read the documentation. This will give you the explanation

Comment: The async function you're passing to `.forEach` is in no way synchronized with the outer async function. The `for` case only has a single async function, so there is clear ordering.

Comment: @loganfsmyth thanks for pointing out the way, I feel like I understand what are you talking, but not exactly. I need to read more document of them, hopefully can get some hint

Answer (score 1):

Think in terms of Promsies (which is what async/await really is)

Int he first case you're chaining the promises, like you would do

```
getData(data[0])
  .then((val) => console.log(...))
  .then(() => getData(data[1])
  .then(...
```

On the second case you're just calling all the promises at once, because `forEach` runs instantly and registers all those promises as you would:

```
data.forEach(x => getData(x).then(val => console.log(...)));
```

Note in this case getData(1) doesn't actually wait for getData(0) to finish - there is no chaining. Your await inside the forEach just chains a then in each of the promises and only captures the next piece of code still inside the forEach

This means that those promises will run asynchronously in regards to each other in the second case.

If you really do want this, but you want to wait for all of the calls to finish (using the second approach) you just need a Promise.all + map approach:

```
const res = await Promise.all(data.map(item => getData(item)));
```

This will effectively bring all the results from getData on each item in the array in a result array, but bare in mind the calls are all async.

Also, there is no way to use the standard `forEach` to make the function wait for eachother. You could use a `reduce` operation instead as such:

```
await data.reduce((intermPromise, item) => intermPromise.then(getData(item)), Promise.resolve());
```

This basically chains the calls to each item by reducing the array, starting with a unit Promise. The final await outside will be applied on the final promise chained with all the calls.

Also note a difference between using the `map` approach - where you actually obtain all the results in an array easily (but it runs async) - and the `reduce` approach - where you get sync calls, but the end result will not return an array, in fact it will return only the result of the last call.

Hope this helps.